# Override `to` behavior by `onClick` action in NavLink(React router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have list of menu tabs that have predefined path and I am using react router to build navigation. So far it worked great, until I received a task to perform sort of validation on user input and depending on that let them switch the tabs. My goal is to override predefined path of `to` in `NavLink` and refer to `useHistory`, which I want to trigger `onClick`.

I can't tell which path would be next, because it depends on user choice and, thus, can't hardcode anything in `to` prop of `NavLink`. Ideally I would want something like this, but it's not working:

```
const validateAndRedirect = (tab) => {
    //call methods to validate user input
    const validate = someDummyValidation(tab);
    if(validate){
        //proceed further
        history.push("/nice/route");
    } else {
        //don't change the route
        history.push(`${tab.base}/${tab.path}`)
    }
}


{tabs.map((x) => (
    <NavLink
        key={x.name}
        to={`${x.base}/${props.path}/`}
        onClick={() => validateAndRedirect(x)}
    >
        {x.name}
    </NavLink>
  ))}
```

This solution is what I would ideally prefer, but it's not working. Indeed, I would prefer to keep `NavLink`, because router does a great job in multiple things that I don't want to re-invent. Another option I had was to use a regular button instead of `NavLink` and give it `onClick` action that would deal with redirection, but I still want to hang out with router. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I would like to use another tag instead of `NavLink` and style it like an `<a />`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `e.preventDefault()`

```
<NavLink
    key={x.name}
    to={`${x.base}/${props.path}/`}
    onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); validateAndRedirect(x);}}
>
```

Or you can use another Component as `NavLink`

```
<FakeLink
  key={x.name}
  onClick={() => validateAndRedirect(x)}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `exact` to the `NavLink` component or build custom tab component.
Please refer to [this](https://github.com/AlgusDark/bloomer/issues/67).
Or you could use `NavLink` of `react-router-dom` rather than `react-router`.